# passing function keys in htop

Tags: keyboard

When using `htop`, the function keys (eg. F9 for kill, F7/F8 for renice..) seem to be captured in the OS rather than in `htop`.  How can I get those keystrokes handled by the process (i.e. `htop`)?  I am using the default gnome terminal in Ubuntu 11.04

[image: htop screencap]

Comment: You don't need to use the function keys, htop uses curses, so you are able to click on the help, setup, search, invert,... buttons with your mouse and they will perform the action.I only state this because I have seen numerous developers and sysadmins not realize this and have the same frustration as you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the gnome-terminal menus, go `Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts...` and uncheck `Enable the menu shortcut key (F10 by default)`.  `F9` seems to work as usual, and `F7/F8` do acually work but seem not to be able to set the nice value lower than zero, not sure why about that one.

Comment: Sir, you're a life saver! :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is a bug. From the `htop` man page:

<kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>

> Increase selected process priority (subtract from 'nice' value). This can be done by the superuser only.

And from `renice` man page (both `htop` and `renice` use the `setpriority C
function`):

> Users other than the super-user may only alter the priority of processes they own, and can only monotonically increase their ‘‘nice value’’ within the range 0 to PRIO_MAX (20).  (This prevents overriding administrative fiats.)

In fact if you try to run htop as root it should work as expected. Thanks to user Flavio Grossi [for this answer](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=404133#10) it absolutely worked!!!

Comment: The tip about trying `f7` as superuser worked for me

Answer (score 1):

One issue may be that **F10** key opens one of the indicators. To solve that, install the CompizConfig Setting Manager

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Then open it:

`ccsm`

Wait for it to open, then choose **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** from the list.

In these settings, change **Key to open the first panel menu** to whatever else you want (default is *F10*).

Comment: unfortunately that did not resolve anything.. and i had ubuntu unity plugin disabled in ccsm anyway.  the F10 key pulls down the File menu in my gnome terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For Gnome Terminal, if You need only a **F10**:

- press "F11" (switch to fullscreen)
- press "F10" (now it will work)
- press "F11" (switch fullscreen back)

profit:)